# How to execute closures serially in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a closure that is executed asynchronously in a `for` loop.

```
for i in 0..<10 {
    closure
}
```

How to make to the for loop wait for the closure to be executed before going into the next iteration?

Comment: You should provide the closure. A closure is executed sync. Most likely code inside the closure is not executed in sync manner. Also, how to you know that is not executed synced?

Comment: The API says it's async, plus I'm printing some lines inside the closures

Comment: Can you point me to the docs where it says closures aren't executed sync? I'm really curious if this is the case.

Comment: it's a block making a network call

Comment: aa, that makes sense, but that means that the closure is executed synced, the network code is executed async, so you have another question

Comment: As has been discussed above, the closure already will be executed synchronously - it's essentially just like a function call. Your problem is that the implementation/body of that closure dispatches some work asynchronously and returns immediately. This is more of a design/contract issue. You will either have to require the code in the closure to block until finished, or use some other mechanism to notify your loop when the work is finished so it can continue.

Comment: @MikeWeller requiring the block to block finish its async task is the main question. The given solutions so far don't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what Max tried to says:

```
var queue = OperationQueue()

queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

for i in 0..<10 {
    queue.addOperation {
        // closure here
    }
}
```

Comment: It's good to have a diversity in answers, but I would personally avoid `OperationQueue`. GCD is a more generally, newer, and more widely used API.

Comment: @Alexander it's ok, it does the same thing. It's a matter of styles.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to use NSOpertations or GCD.  See [Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch)
or you could use [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org) if you're doing this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very simply with `Dispatch`:

```
import Dispatch // Necessary for DispatchQueue
import Foundation // Necessary for sleep

let closures = [ //The array of closures to execute serially
    { print(1); sleep(1) },
    { print(2); sleep(1) },
    { print(3); sleep(1) },
    { print(4); sleep(1) },
    { print(5); sleep(1) }
]

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "My Serial Queue") // TODO: Name me

for closure in closures {
    queue.sync(execute: closure)
}

// Alternatively:
// closures.forEach(queue.sync(execute:))
```

Comment: Can that queue be the main queue?

Comment: @Carpsen90 If you want, sure. Keep in mind that means that your closures won't necessarily run consecutively (other work items can be performed between yours)

Comment: So in the for loop I could use `DispatchQueue.main.sync`?

Comment: @Carpsen90 yep.

Answer (score 0):

You can add them to an `OperationQueue` and set its `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1. Then run them.

Comment: Can you show how that would be written inside the for loop?